# distance between sets defnition and problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $. define their distance to be

$$ d(A,B) = \inf_{a \in A, b \in B} |a-b| $$

Proposition: Suppose $A$ is closed set and $b \in \mathbb{R}^2$ arbitrary. Then there exists some $x \in A$ such that $d(A,b) = |x-b| $

*Try*:

Let $a \in A$. Since $A$ is closed, we can find a sequence $a_n \to a $. So, for all $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $N$ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon $ for all $n \geq N$. In particular, for $n = N$, it must be the case that $|a_N -a | < \epsilon $. We claim that $x = a_N$ is the desired point we are looking for: Notice

$$ |x - b| \leq |x-a| + |a-b | \leq \epsilon + d(A,b)$$

and so $|x-b| \leq d(A,b) $.

Next, since for every $a \in A$ we have that $\inf |a-b| \leq |a-b| $, it must be the case that $d(A,b) \leq |x-b| $

and the result follows.

Question: Is this a correct solution? Thanks in advance for any useful commentary.

Comment: No seems wrong how is $|a-b|\leq d(A,b)$

Comment: infimum is attained only if set is compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have noted, compactness and continuity are the easiest ways to approach this problem. First show $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous. Fix $x,y\in X$. Then for any $a\in A$, we have $d(x,A)\le|x-a|\le|x-y|+|y-a|$, so $d(x,A)-|x-y|\le |x-a|$. Since this is true for all $a\in A$ we have $d(x,A)-|x-y|\le d(y,A)$, which rearranges to $d(x,A)-d(y,A)\le|x-y|$. Interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ we get
$d(y,A)-d(x,A)\le|y-x|=|x-y|$. Hence $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\le|x-y|$, so the map $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is uniformly continuous.

Now define $B=\{x\in A\,:\,|x-b|\le 2d(b,A)\}$. Then $B\subseteq A$, so $d(b,A)\le d(b,B)$. However for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ (in fact if $0<\epsilon<d(b,A)$), if $a\in A$ satisfies $|b-a|<d(b,A)+\epsilon$ then we have $a\in B$, so in fact $d(b,B)=d(b,A)$. It is not hard to see $B$ is closed and bounded, and hence compact, so there exists $x\in B$ such that $d(b,B)=|x-b|$. This immediately implies $x\in A$ and $d(b,A)=|x-b|$.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your argument.

- You say that $|x-b| \leq |x-a| + |a-b| \leq \epsilon + d(A, b)$. But it should be the other way round: $d(A, b) \leq |a-b|$ for all $a\in A$ (by definition of $d(A, b)$.
- You seem to want to take $\epsilon \to 0$, but $x$ is chosen depending on $\epsilon$. Thus you cannot do that.

Note that compactness (I am not saying that $A$ has to be compact) has to be used somewhere in your proof. Your choice of $x$ is so arbitrary.

A formal proof would be something like this:

Let $a_n \in A$ be a sequence in $A$ so that $d(a_n, b) \to d(A, b)$ (By definition of $d(A, b)$, such a sequence exist). Then when $n$ is large, we have that

$$a_n \in A \cap \overline {B_r(b)}$$

for some fixed large $r$. Then as $A \cap \overline {B_r(b)}$ is closed and bounded, $a_n \to a$ for some $a\in A \cap \overline {B_r(b)}\subset A$. What can you say about $|a-b|$?

Comment: How can I show that $A$ is bounded? so that $A$ becomes compact.

Comment: You are not actually showing that $A$ is bounded. Indeed to calculate $d(A, b)$, it suffices to consider those element $a$ in $A$ which is close to $b$. @ILoveMath

Comment: Can I start saying that for every $\epsilon > 0$ , there is some $a \in A $ such that $|a-b| < d(A,b) + \epsilon $ ?? (by definition of infimum)

Comment: @ILoveMath: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: I think I got it: Since $A$ is closed we can take a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n \to a $ and so we can make $|a_n-a|$ small. Hence,

$$ |a-b| \leq |a-a_n| + |a_n-b| < \epsilon + d(A,b) + \epsilon $$

Therefore, by letting $\epsilon \to 0$, we have $|a-b| \leq d(A,b) $. IS this correct?

Comment: @ILoveMath: You just didn't tell how your $a_n$ and $a$ are chosen. But from the inequalities I can kind of guess your choice. Please see the edit.

Comment: how is that possible that $d(a_n,b) \to d(A,b)$?

Comment: Think about the definition of $d(A, b)$. @ILoveMath

Comment: for $a_n \in A$, By definition for all $n$, we have 

$$ |a_n - b| < d(A,b) + \frac{1}{n} $$
this is why your first line follows?

Comment: @ILoveMath It seems to me that you have some sequence $a_n$ in mind. Can you tell me what that is? The sequence I was thinking about can be constructed using your method, but it doesn't have to be (Can also be something like $|a_n - b| \leq d(A, b) +\frac 2n$ for example).

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. In your calculation $$|x-b|\leq|x-a|+|a-b|\leq\epsilon+d(A,b)$$you assume that $|a-b|\leq d(A,b)$ which is not true in general. Also note that the point $a$ you chose is actually arbitrary ("let $a\in A$" means this holds for any $a$ in $A$), and so is your choice of a sequence that converge to $a$. By not specifying *how* you choose the sequence, or the point $a$, any choice is valid. For example, consider the constant sequence $a_n=a$, it converges to $a$. Combining this with your arbitrary $a$ you basically just showed that any $a$ in $A$ is at the same distance from $b$, namely $d(A,b)$, which is rather surprising, since $A$ is *any* closed set.

You are correct in relying heavily on the fact that $A$ is closed, this would not be true otherwise. But you should probably use it to deduce your final result, rather than generate some artifact in your solution; if this makes any sense.

Some concrete clues how to reach a solution (read carefully, this might lead you to the solution too quickly. try to read each bullet and then solve it yourself before reading more) - You need to consider

- The properties of the distance $d(A,b)$ as an infimum.
- The fact that the distance function is a continuous function.
- The fact that $A$ is closed.

Comment: Can I start saying that for every $\epsilon > 0$ , there is some $a \in A $ such that $|a-b| < d(A,b) + \epsilon $ ?? (by definition of infimum)

Comment: Yes, by choose $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ you can construct a sequence $a_n \in A$. What can you say about its limit and its distance to b?